# Detecting file completion using WatchService in java

Tags: java, watchservice

I have a file which is being constantly written to, while it is registered with watchService. 
Is it possible to detect that it has completed, using WatchEvent.

Please note that, by complete, I mean the previous writer which was writing to the file has finished and I expect no-one else to open that file and write.

Comment: you could use a timeout (say 1 sec) for how long no new modification event was received and than assume the writing process is completed. This could help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html#poll-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same problem on Windows paltform.
I have tried to solve it using timeout: when a timeout of 1 second for example is elapsed (since the last modify event), I consider that file is complete. But it is not working for big files: I have remark that a modify event is fired after the timeout.
In my application, I copy files on a directory. I solved the problem by copying a temporary file after the copy of my file. In this case, when a create event is fired for the temporary file, the first file is complete.

N.B: for linux platform, I've done some searching and I find a suggestion to use renameTo() method to check if the file still locked by a process. If the remaneTo() returns true, your file is complete.
In my project, which is Windows dependant, I tried renameTo() but I get a true value and the file is not complete.